# Is there a humanitarian crisis in Gaza, according to the government of Israel?

Tags: israel, gaza

According to an interview given to Sky News by the Israeli ambassador to the UK, [posted](https://news.sky.com/story/israel-hamas-war-latest-updates-gaza-sky-news-live-blog-12978800?postid=6587422#liveblog-body) about three hours ago: "There is no humanitarian crisis" in Gaza.

Nearly simultaneously Reuters [headlines](https://www.reuters.com/world/middle-east/gaza-border-crossing-set-reopen-israeli-troops-prepare-ground-assault-2023-10-15/) "Israeli strikes on Gaza intensify as humanitarian crisis deepens".

So, given that ambassadors [can](https://uk.news.yahoo.com/baltics-express-fury-completely-unacceptable-095806186.html) sometimes say stuff that's not in line with the official position of their governments, is that the official position of the Israeli government too, that there's no humanitarian crisis in Gaza today?

Comment: I found [a quote of the Minister of Defense](https://www.timesofisrael.com/liberman-theres-no-humanitarian-crisis-in-gaza-we-wont-spend-a-penny/) from 2018 saying that "there's no humanitarian crisis in Gaza", but I don't know if that's still the official position